# NUnit: How to write one generic test method for three functions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm using NUnit. Here is my requirement:

Let's say there are 3 functions namely `add()`, `sub()` and `mul()`. How to write just one generic test method in Nunit?

So depending on the function type the generic test method execute the tests.

Means if I pass `add()` to generic test method it should perform the test for `add()` and so on. I do not want to write 3 separate test methods for 3 methods.

I just want to accomplish this using just one generic test method. Is this possible?

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to write 3 separate methods? Because it is possible you will end up with MORE code that is harder to read if you try to cram all 3 cases into one test method.  Which also reminds me, a generic test is just a bad idea. I mean what is it testing? That the function call is successful? The unit test should be testing something of value.

Comment: A test should be easy to write. I rather have 3 methods which are easy to read then figure out the clever code written for a test. I don't even recommend inheritance etc in tests. Tests should be simple and intuitive.

Comment: @meganaut Thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't understand what *good* unit tests are about.

The intention of a unit test is to help you to quickly identify the root cause of failure, in order to fix it as quickly as possible.

That starts with the simple fact that you have **one** test for each "different behavior" you intend to test. In other words: you definitely go for **one** test method for each of your 3 test methods.

You might even go for **multiple** test methods for those 3 methods; because "adding to empty" *could* be a different thing then "adding to non-empty" for example.

Probably you want to have some "integration" level test that really uses all three of your methods in one test case; just to make sure that the overall "plumbing" works out in the end. But from a unit test level, you make sure that those three methods work as expected on a **per method** level. You know, when you really **verified** that add() works in all possible scenarios; there is no more special need to test it in conjunction with those other methods!

Comment: You mentioned above that I could go for one test method for each of my 3 methods. How to do that? Could you show me the way please?